# Push Notification to start a scene

Tags: unity, ios, scene, server-push

I was wondering whether I can use APNs in iOS to trigger an event in my game, like start a scene without user clicking the notification. Is it possible to use remote push notifications for events like this?

Comment: Did you Google it first? [First result](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.google.com%2Fdocument%2Fd%2F1uASypQ6NLfNfu4AMhXtTaA8FZc8olkJt3Wn5LUszeVQ%2Fedit&ei=jJ8-VMWvBs_liwKfzYHwAg&usg=AFQjCNHoRUC_TM_aXdwWekJuTjM8xDehgA)

Comment: I don't know whether the above comment was bot-generated. I'm a noob (you can get that from the question) and what I know about the push notifications is that they have to be clicked by the user for the app to respond. In my case, the user will not click the notification(also mentioned in the question). Sorry for being rude, :P I always feel offended when someone say that I didn't google.

Comment: Sorry, not bot generated, just terse. Maybe you can expand your question to include what you've tried, and why it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible. Many push notification plugins will execute a callback inside your game if a notification is received while the game is running.

Inside this callback you can load your desired scene.